# ReactiveForms: input type "file" reset by addControl()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

In a Angular 7 and ReactiveForm, if i put a file in `<input type="file">`, and i add a row with `formgroup.addControl()`, all the `<input type="file">` are reset.

I'm stuck because `type="file"` can't be again init, with a personal fonction, because they must be init with a string null value.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvk6nb

I need to keep the `type="file"` values when i add rows with addControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form structure is off. If you were to put `<pre>{{formgroup.value | json}}</pre>` in your stackblitz, you would see that the structure is not correct and is causing you issues.

This seems like a perfect use of a `FormArray` instead, so that is what I would suggest:

```ts
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // wrap the formarray inside a formgroup
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    files: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.initRow()
    ])
  })
}

// called when adding a new row
addRow() {
  (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('files')).push(this.initRow());
}

// creates and returns a new formgroup
initRow() {
  const blanckForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [''],
    file: ''
  });
  return blanckForm;
}
```

And your template would look like:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="files">
    <div *ngFor="let file of myForm.get('files').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="name" type="text">
      <input formControlName="file" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<input type="button" (click)="addRow()" value="ADD ROW">
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prtvgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**